# How to make an object permanently disappear after clicking on it once in Libreoffice Impress?

Tags: macros, microsoft-powerpoint, libreoffice, openoffice, presentations

I am hosting a trivia night in my middle school next week. I plan to use LibreOffice Impress. In the first slide there are multiple topics to choose from. When I click on one, it moves to the slide that contains the corresponding question. After a contestant answers the question and the points are added or deducted, I click the arrow at the bottom right to return to the first slide.

The problem we discovered in a trial run is that when there are dozens of topics to choose from, the contestants had trouble tracking which topics were already selected. This wasted a lot of time since every time they selected a topic that was already used we had to prompt them to select another one, which could repeat when there are few topics left.

I tried adding exit animations but they reset once we come back and the order of animations is immutable so it didn't work. How can I make the topics permanently disappear during the entire presentation after it is clicked on once? Do I need to use LibreOffice Basic Macros? If there is an MS Office exclusive feature I could consider switching to PowerPoint

[First Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hCETN.jpg)

[Question Slide](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3ehSb.jpg)

[How First Slide should look after selecting Biology, then coming back](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1plN0.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

On the question slide, instead of the arrow create a Command button from the Developer tab and name something like "Go back". Right click on the button and choose "View code". This will bring you into the VB Application.

[image]

In the CommandButton window that has opened you should have the following text:

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()


End Sub
```

Just insert the following code in between and then save the file as .potm (Microsoft Powerpoint macro-enabled template)

```
ActivePresentation.Slides(1).Shapes("shape_name").Visible = False
    With SlideShowWindows(1).View
    .GotoSlide 1
End With
```

You should replace "shape_name" with the name of the shape you want to disappear when you return back. Also at ".GotoSlide 1" with the number of the slide you want to go back to. If the topics slide is your first one in the presentation then leave it "1".

---

**How make the Developer TAB appear**

```
File -> Options -> Customize Ribbon -> In the list of Main Tabs check the Developer box. DONE!
```

**How to see the name of the shapes**

```
Home -> Arange -> Selection pane...
```

---

*Also reminder to add animations and images to make it more fun.*